# Plots don't consistently appear in PyCharm IPython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter

MATLAB -> Python convert trying to get IPython notebooks to work.  Running PyCharm 2016.3.2 and Python 2.7.13 through Anaconda2 on Windows 7.

I have an IPython notebook that runs just fine on my machine Jupyter that I'm trying to run outside of a browser.  The minimum working example that shows the behavior is broken out into two cells.  First cell is the function definition (cut down for demo purposes) and the second (and subsequent cells not shown) repeatedly call the first:

```
def spectrumPlot(NspectraFiles, laserLines, gaussAmp):

    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



    def rgb(r, g, b):
        outMap = (float(r)/255, float(g)/255, float(b)/255)
        return outMap

    def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
        return np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))

    def genData(gaussAmp):

        csv = np.empty([550, 3])
        csv[:,0] = np.linspace(350, 900, 550)
        csv[:,1] = gaussAmp*gaussian(csv[:,0], np.random.rand(1)*550 + 350, 100)
        csv[:,2] = gaussAmp*gaussian(csv[:,0], np.random.rand(1)*550 + 350, 100)

        return csv



    fluorColorCycle = [rgb(155, 89, 182),
                       rgb(52, 152, 219),
                       rgb(46, 204, 113),
                       rgb(230, 126, 34),
                       rgb(192, 57, 43)]

    for k in range(0, NspectraFiles):

        dataHere = genData(gaussAmp)

        plt.plot(dataHere[:,0], dataHere[:,1], color=fluorColorCycle[k], ls = '--', linewidth=0.5)
        plt.plot(dataHere[:,0], dataHere[:,2], color=fluorColorCycle[k], linewidth = 2)

    # Add in lasers

    for k in range(0, len(laserLines)):

        plt.plot([laserLines[k], laserLines[k]], [0, 100], color = fluorColorCycle[k], linewidth = 5)

    plt.xlabel('Wavelength (nm)', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('Intensity (a.u.)', fontsize=14)
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10, 5]
    plt.xlim(350, 900)

    plt.show()
```

---

```
NspectraFiles = 5

laserLines = [405, 488, 561, 637, 730]

spectrumPlot(NspectraFiles, laserLines, 45)
```

---

What should happen after executing these two cells is that I get a plot that appears showing some vertical colored bars at the indicated 'laserLines' positions and amplitude of 100 and NspectraFiles randomly-placed Gaussian peaks of amplitude of the third argument to spectrumPlot (45 here).  *But* if that third argument is greater than 45, then the plot doesn't always appear.  If it's between ~44-50 then the plot will appear but won't

I've tried setting

```
%matplotlib inline
```

under the import statements in the first cell.  This makes the plots reliably appear but I cannot seem to re-size them with the

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
```

property.

Any help on why the plots wouldn't appear based on a calculation parameter?  Or a work-around that allows me to still modify the plot size?

Comment: I think you should place plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10, 5] before the plot commands. to correctly set the figure size before plotting curves.

Comment: Placing that line immediately after the import statements and %matplotlib inline means the figure will be generated at the proper size, but are subject to the issue with the plot not appearing if the amplitude is too large.

Placing %matplotlib inline as the first line in the first cell gives the same behavior (plots defined size, but don't appear if amplitude > ~45).

Comment: I am using jupyter notebook and python 2.7.13, i placed plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10, 5] before the plot commands. I can plot for amplitude > 45 ( tried 60, 100 etc) consistently. Can you try in jupyter notebook?

Comment: Like I mentioned, this runs fine in Jupyter.  I don't want to use Jupyter, however, and am trying to understand how to get this to work outside of the browser environment.